# Cookies from backend service not visible in Postman using zuul routing

Tags: cookies, netflix-zuul, cloud-foundry

I have a zuul routing app deployed on the cloud. Below in my application.yml

```
---
spring:
 profiles: default

zuul:
 routes:
  cloud:
   path: /cardsvcs/acs/**
   sensitiveHeaders:
   url: https://vst0.mapi.checkFin.com/
   stripPrefix: false

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

Routing works perfectly fine and I also get the response headers back from the back end service. The requestContext originResponseHeaders also have all the cookies as part of setCookie header. But these cookies are not visible on the Postman response after routing.

Do we need to gets the cookies from this header in the filter and map them again?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Authorization
```

The sentive-headers that are configured in zuul are not passed to downstream servers. And below three headers are defaults.

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

To pass cookie related headers to your downstream server, you need to redefine above propeprties.

Please refer to the section 'Cookies and Sensitive Headers' in the the linked doc : http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.RELEASE/

Comment: I tried this but still my cookies didn't show up. I figure out that the cookies are coming from a different domain as compared to the domain from which routing is triggered. If I map it to the request domain, cookies do show up.